# EDSDK - Request AutoFocus without stopping liveview image retrieval

Tags: c#, c++, edsdk, canon-sdk

I would like to be able to autofocus while retrieving images from the liveview.

In my case, when I autofocus, the image retrieval stops and starts again once I get the autofocus command back.
I autofocus the camera using the :

`SendCommand(kEdsCameraCommand_PressShutterButton, kEdsCameraCommand_ShutterButton_Halfway);`

Is this possible? This function is available via Canon's EOS Utility application.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: can i ask u something? where u download the edsdk? can u send it?